# How do I treat two children classes of the same parent class, as the same, yet different Type?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, types, interface, typescript-generics

I need help in figuring out how to properly assert a type in typescript.

The code that I'm working with is confusing rn (I think I made it more complicated than it needed to be lol :3) so I will just give you the overview of what I'm trying to accomplish.

So basically I have a **ConcreteFactory** class that implements the **IAbstractFactory** interface. The **ConcreteFactory** class can create/produce 3 different Concrete Classes **BaseDocument**, **DocumentA**, and **DocumentB**.

```
interface IAbstractFactory{
    createBaseDocument(): Promise<IAbstractDocument>;
    createDocumentA(): Promise<IAbstractDocument>;
    createDocumentB(): Promise<IAbstractDocument>;
}

class ConcreteFactory implements IAbstractFactory{
    public async createBaseDocument(): Promise<IAbstractDocument> {
        return new BaseDocument();
    }

    public async createDocumentA(): Promise<IAbstractDocument> {
        return new DocumentA();
    }

    public async createDocumentB(): Promise<IAbstractDocument> {
        return new DocumentB();
    }
}
```

Note that only the Document class implements the **IAbstractDocument** interface. DocumentA and DocumentB both extend **BaseDocument**.

```
interface IAbstractDocument{
    methodBase(){};
}

class BaseDocument implements IAbstractDocument{
    methodBase(){};
}

// uses all of BaseDocuments functions but has some extra functions that DocumentB does not have
class DocumentA extends BaseDocument{
    methodBase(){}; 
    methodA(){}; // not implemented in IAbstractDocument, throws error
}

// uses all of BaseDocuments functions but has some extra functions that DocumentA does not have 
class DocumentB extends BaseDocument{
    methodBase(){}; 
    methodB(){}; // not implemented in IAbstractDocument, throws error
}
```

I also have a class called **Tree** which will build a Tree, with each node being of type **IAbstractDocument**

```
class Tree{
    rootNode:IAbstractDocument; // Realistically of type DocumentA or DocumentB, IAbstractDocument is throwing error, explained below
    
    nodes: IAbstractDocument[]; // Realistically of type DocumentA or DocumentB, IAbstractDocument is throwing error, explained below

    // this function will create factory and the factory will create DocumentA or Document B
    createDocument(){}

    addDocument()

}
```

My goal is to create a Tree of Documents. The rules are **DocumentA** can contain children nodes, both of type **DocumentA** or **DocumentB**, but **DocumentB** cannot have any children (they can only be leaf nodes).

**The problem is:**

Although **DocumentA** and **DocumentB** both extend **BaseDocument**. In the **Tree** class they are defined under the type **IAbstractDocument** (I did this because I thought that's what the **ConcreteFactory** is returning). So now I getting an error that the unique functions in **DocumentA** and **DocumentB**(methodA and methodB, respectively) are not defined in **IAbstractDocument**. So I cannot use them in the **Tree** class, I can only use **methodBase()**.

**My question is:**

**How do I treat both **DocumentA** and **DocumentB** as the same yet different Type?** They should both be considered Document Nodes in **Tree**, but they have different functions related to them.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Ympbpw) so that others can reproduce your issue (any errors you are talking about should be evident) and only your issue (other errors like typos or undeclared dependencies should be removed). It's a lot easier to help if I can start working on the answer immediately and not have to work on the question first.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about `Tree` here; shouldn't the `nodes` be other `Tree` instances?  And if you have such differing requirements for the child/leaf distinction, you probably want `Tree` itself to be subclassable and have a `DocumentATree` and a `DocumentBTree`.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) and avoid the general base/abstract versions.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3e3w) work for you or give you direction?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate in your question.

Comment: Im sorry if I didn't give a reproducible example, I should've thought about that. The Union types do make sense and I think that's the answer I needed. Thank you! But what did you mean by having the nodes be other Tree instances? Is it better for performance to split the Tree into multiple sub Trees? I was trying to recreate the functionality of this Tree traversal Algorithm [bfs-dfs-example](https://github.com/AvraamMavridis/Algorithms-Data-Structures-in-Typescript/blob/master/algorithms/bfs-dfs.md), except I wanted to replace ```TreeNode``` with ```DocumentA``` and/or ```DocumentB```.

Comment: Also there's one other thing I wanted to clarify about the two types of Documents. I'm sorry if I didn't explain it well, but DocumentA is acting as a type of "Collection"(DocA) of other "sub-collections"(DocA) or "sub-Items"(DocB). And DocumentB is just acting as an Item, that can exist by itself(root node) or be the child of a "Collection/sub-Collection"(DocA). So an example of the Tree structure could be DocA -> [DocB, DocB] **OR** DocA -> [DocA, DocA] -> [[DocB, DocB], [DocB, DocB]] **OR** DocB

Comment: I did not realize that `DocumentA` itself was a node in a tree and that it had a collection in it.  I still don't see a [mcve] here; while I may write up an answer, I can't guarantee that it matches your use case.

Comment: It is fine for the `ConcreteFactory` to return a type that is *more specific* than what's in the `IAbstractFactory` interface.  `createDocumentA` can return `Promise<DocumentA>`.  My two cents: if there is only one concretion of an `IAbstractFactory` then there's not really any point in having a separate interface for it.  Typescript classes are also interfaces, so you can use `ConcreteFactory` as a type.

Comment: *"Note that only the Document class implements the IAbstractDocument interface. DocumentA and DocumentB both extend BaseDocument."* In typescript, implementation of an interface is automatic.  Say you have `interface IAbstractDocument{ methodBase(): void; }`.  If there is a function that requires an `IAbstractDocument`, you can give it **any** object with a `void` `methodBase()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will likely want to use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) to represent "either-or", and not the superclass or other base types, which can't be checked as easily.  In general you should probably use as specific a type as necessary to allow the compiler to know what you're doing.

In what followed I will be changing the name `DocumentA` to `DocumentCollection` and `DocumentB` to `DocumentSingle` since I think that's what your intent is.  A `DocumentCollection` will have a `children` property, and a `DocumentSingle` will not.  Here's `ConcreteFactory`:

```
class ConcreteFactory {
    public async createBaseDocument(): Promise<BaseDocument> {
        return new BaseDocument();
    }

    public async createDocumentCollection(): Promise<DocumentCollection> {
        return new DocumentCollection();
    }

    public async createDocumentSingle(): Promise<DocumentSingle> {
        return new DocumentSingle();
    }
}
```

See how it returns more specific types in its return signature.  Now let's look at possible implementations for your `Document` classes:

```
class BaseDocument {
    methodBase() { };
    constructor(public docName: string = "") { }
}

class DocumentCollection extends BaseDocument {
    methodBase() { };
    methodCollection() { console.log("MethodCollection by " + this.docName) };
    children: Array<DocumentCollection> | Array<DocumentSingle> = [];
}

class DocumentSingle extends BaseDocument {
    methodBase() { };
    methodSingle() { console.log("MethodSingle by " + this.docName) };
}
```

I've given documents a `docName` so we can see some useful output later.  Note how the `children` property of `DocumentCollection` is either an `Array<DocumentCollection>` or an `Array<DocumentSingle>`.  This will prevent it from being a mixed collection which, if I understand correctly from your question, you want to prohibit.  Note that it's harder to use a union-of-arrays than it is to use an array-of-unions, but it is what it is.

Let's give a name to the union of `DocumentSingle` and `DocumentCollection`:

```
type Document = DocumentSingle | DocumentCollection;
```

You will probably want to use `Document` instead of `AbstractDocument` or `BaseDocument`, if you can help it.

---

Now let's look at `Tree`:

```
class Tree {

    nodes: Document[]
    constructor(public rootNode: Document) {
        this.nodes = [];
        const addNodes = (x: Document): void => {
            this.nodes.push(x)
            if ("children" in x) {
                x.children.forEach(addNodes)
            }
        }
        addNodes(this.rootNode);

    }
    walk(
      processSingle: (x: DocumentSingle) => void, 
      processCollection: (x: DocumentCollection) => void
    ) {
        const walk = (x: Document): void => {
            if ("methodSingle" in x) {
                processSingle(x);
            } else {
                processCollection(x);
                x.children.forEach(walk)
            }
        }
        walk(this.rootNode);
    }
}
```

A `Tree` has a `rootNode` of type `Document`.  It also has a `nodes` array of type `Document[]`.  When you construct a `Tree` with its `rootNode`, the constructor will also walk the tree to build up the `nodes` array, if it matters.  There's also a `walk()` method which takes processor callbacks for `DocumentSingle` and `DocumentCollection` and walks through the tree calling the appropriate processor.

Note that in the implementation of both the `addNodes()` and `walk()` arrow functions, the compiler uses the presence of one of the specific properties of `DocumentSingle` or `DocumentCollection` to narrow a `Document` to one of the two members.  That works because [the `in` operator can be used as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#type-guards-inferred-from-in-operator).

---

So let's make a `Tree`:

```
const leafOne = new DocumentSingle("leafOne");
const leafTwo = new DocumentSingle("leafTwo");
const leafThree = new DocumentSingle("leafThree");
const leafFour = new DocumentSingle("leafFour");

const branchOne = new DocumentCollection("branchOne");
branchOne.children = [leafOne, leafTwo];

const branchTwo = new DocumentCollection("branchTwo");
branchTwo.children = [leafThree, leafFour];

const root = new DocumentCollection("root");
// note how I'm not allowed to assign a mixed thing to root.children
root.children = [branchOne, leafOne];

root.children = [branchOne, branchTwo]; // okay

const tree = new Tree(root);
```

You can see from the above that you are not allowed to use a mixed array of `DocumentSingle` and `DocumentCollection` in the `children` property of a `DocumentCollection`.  Also you should note that I *reassigned* the `children` property with a fresh array instead of trying to `push()` onto it.  If you try a `push()` you'll find that it won't let you add anything, because it doesn't know if the array holds `DocumentSingle`s or `DocumentCollection`s. Not sure if this is a dealbreaker or not for your use case, but if so we can change it.  (Well, *you* can change it; I don't know that I can commit to it ⏳)

Great, we have a `tree`... let's `walk()` it:

```
tree.walk(x => x.methodSingle(), y => y.methodCollection());
/* [LOG]: "MethodCollection by root" 
[LOG]: "MethodCollection by branchOne" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafOne" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafTwo" 
[LOG]: "MethodCollection by branchTwo" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafThree" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafFour" */
```

Great! Alternatively, we could iterate its `nodes` property:

```
tree.nodes.forEach(x => "methodSingle" in x ? x.methodSingle() : x.methodCollection());
/* [LOG]: "MethodCollection by root" 
[LOG]: "MethodCollection by branchOne" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafOne" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafTwo" 
[LOG]: "MethodCollection by branchTwo" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafThree" 
[LOG]: "MethodSingle by leafFour" */
```

Looks good.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAJMYkG8BQ2n6XgBsQookBhAe2HgCcIAXCAMQUaroE8s8D+YAVwBGRAJbwkpLrUIMQzAEKkIAESrxBkYIwAUASgBcSAAp0qYMVAgAeZdfWbtjAHy9+Hgg0aC6wJMAQAO5I9moaWhA6BgDcfJ4Avrie+EKiElJQMpL0EArhTlGM1EREEPCMYjQGxmYWVraOkTolZRVVwG44KR7evv6BIU3OreWV1fpxPUnxHmniktKyufnDRQDKYsAA5mU1puaW1jZrOps7ZV2zPX1+AcFIp4znuxCx1wRJ-DOzxKTkYSe7hSkEYAAsqAATMIGLBIBJTFLwGhQRh0QQVTi6eYZSEaABy4AgxlRdC22yQAF4kAAiGn6OFfT7JAh-MiPCIjKilMYdJAQAAezGAkIBKiB3RBTAh0JUsMw8MRnlBMtG7QmcORwCg3IgADoiFRtroaQBZaVQtXjfzCHg0pAAaiQ4Kserx8EJkAZCI++HgYLEREhDGAxgAgnQ6CAuCdOUUrR03AAfJARqMxp4vS5UpAAbQAukr4Sy-SR2ZnyWV+UKoqLQuK4zpgcqLbLrPLFb6kCqoVm3gyFVqdWUDUaTebwb3K8hbbTHc6A1A3QSid6izN+IwuDBkEDqRWLsgU08EzQ4r8y+QACoMZCSzzAKHQYxPAtdodojEcOjYkQLJDmFQjD4k+L6NowA5dpui56o+kLQDmBZFj0H5SJCkIgfB5DUroApgYUOhGEgABuVBiJCVJXD0PQukucHQHqQhQGCuH6FBKRiAAZkgJr+oGwZRPaWxIAKkHUeJIl6nxQYhnqnGcAAoggLEgOhmHQGxEkeEy4k6dRqkYU+UC6LReqAcBT6TCW2ldkEIBEAA1ti5iIGQfbGLh+HNM804MpSbikeRAA0SAwC50BQKeoY8XhHIEcU3JtNafkBWRkJiRJqF2Y5OaeXF3lEYFFH+c2WlIFxPE0j2kJ9kJ-iiaVZUEGFGgRX2rHIRJCT8kQ1iNU1oXhWQUUdex4kClJAYyVEcmKcpujZQ5mkDXp0xjUgi0mTB5nqVZa3fLgvwoowSBlCAnEAPKBDmgz5c47U0mdl2BPSRaoU9V5BFQN0PAerwmh9X2vUd2onR9YK3j9QzgQ94O3sD-DvXknEsFQvhQ3dGzTgDyOo74wMg6iSDCFGtBgldyDUrdJ6Jby1Q0iTIBkxTCMEIzzOBJN-EhohT0UyFgNUIW1moez-qfd9VO-eBI0M6T4tA3tbPy2CEtc9N-jUrmcMQBAAu42jdDC4TJ3mRjNM8uqwAmuZrP4AA9PbARAcgEIhAAkgA5Bgj4nfZhpBBAFEcJkUBiNs-ggN2YgCkHC7ks633merAnALMyfSaniFi+TgT6+dFPG-wGdTVnWs5-zxMqxLhZII7SBUA50Yi8dzqQ1LIQ3rrujmVZsxorreqbQKlGSdV7X6CFPAlVwerVSN+hKw7ABUeYADIXQA4vmxhmq2UXEzwttILMuYb9vu8TqqtNW4fVdM-6LMn-wZ9bzvtJX1Oh533zL3PwQr8L4f1bH2H+yMJb2lPufd+e9JyQgPrOHOED-74EATAz+NVpxgPOleCGutIEv2gZfEBWDZxPTxnQe0y97aHU3LeWCRlZp0CUv6XCo8qokMPHVESSAAD8Y9OH-QZMYCa88b7WgMEvOuq80HELgQgo+VAgIEIAUQ4B8jxF8kQSrJ+UC35yJlKAshyNdGEP0eowxpCeCCxUagtRsDr6W2tHfJBQMUHr3MQ4r+rxsGcVwfDdxsiLHeKrMY86FCqE0OwAkIAA)